# Unable to autoplot data frame time series in R

Tags: r

I am trying to complete a time series forecast the number of calls that will come in by month for the next 2 years using the following Dataset

https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/12d55393-2c84-4681-8c04-dc43775dbdfd/resource/62b40b15-a010-4fe7-8d56-d631802231be

I used the line of business Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)

The data includes 3 columns: The line of business for the call, the date (month & year) and the numbers of calls handled.

For my preliminary analysis, I'm attempting to use the `autoplot` function but am running into issues. I've tried the following code.

```
# Load the forecasting package
library(fpp3)

# Load the Data
load(Book3)

# Declare time series data
Book3 <- ts( Book3, [,3], start = 2016,1, frequency = 12)

############################################
Preliminary analysis
############################################
#Time Plot
autoplot(Book3) + 
  ggtitle("Test plot") + 
  ylab("Calls Handled")
```

"Book3"  being the name of my dataset. The issue however is that when I try and run it, I get the following error:

```
Error in `autoplot()`:
! Objects of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame not supported by autoplot.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Dataset can also be reconstructed using the bellow:

```
structure(list(`Queue Group/Line of Business` = c("Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", 
"Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)", "Driver and Vehicle Services queues (English + French)"
), DATE = c("2016-Jan", "2016-Feb", "2016-Mar", "2016-Apr", "2016-May", 
"2016-Jun", "2016-Jul", "2016-Aug", "2016-Sep", "2016-Oct", "2016-Nov", 
"2016-Dec", "2017-Jan", "2017-Feb", "2017-Mar", "2017-Apr", "2017-May", 
"2017-Jun", "2017-Jul", "2017-Aug", "2017-Sep", "2017-Oct", "2017-Nov", 
"2017-Dec", "2018-Jan", "2018-Feb", "2018-Mar", "2018-Apr", "2018-May", 
"2018-Jun", "2018-Jul", "2018-Aug", "2018-Sep", "2018-Oct", "2018-Nov", 
"2018-Dec", "2019-Jan", "2019-Feb", "2019-Mar", "2019-Apr", "2019-May", 
"2019-Jun", "2019-Jul", "2019-Aug", "2019-Sep", "2019-Oct", "2019-Nov", 
"2019-Dec", "2020-Jan", "2020-Feb", "2020-Mar", "2020-Apr", "2020-May", 
"2020-Jun", "2020-Jul", "2020-Aug", "2020-Sep", "2020-Oct", "2020-Nov", 
"2020-Dec", "2021-Jan", "2021-Feb", "2021-Mar", "2021-Apr", "2021-May", 
"2021-Jun", "2021-Jul", "2021-Aug", "2021-Sep"), `Calls Handled` = c(70660, 
61905, 63322, 68323, 72465, 67761, 64797, 77825, 71506, 71563, 
73651, 62384, 78243, 66130, 72600, 57756, 71920, 75819, 73144, 
82160, 70994, 73033, 66115, 53979, 71682, 57638, 66280, 56167, 
75368, 70826, 73149, 79144, 70100, 72516, 63654, 53070, 73814, 
57584, 66132, 63191, 72111, 63801, 68660, 67934, 57454, 56167, 
49349, 45312, 60766, 50218, 56790, 62748, 84383, 95169, 79610, 
70333, 80930, 75381, 77950, 78096, 73031, 60816, 89674, 74114, 
74114, 74717, 64373, 64202, 99922)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -69L))
```

Comment: `autoplot` doesn't understand data frames. It is used to plot some common types of R object, such as time series or the output of `lm`. It doesn't know which columns of the data frame you want to use - so you should use `ggplot()`.

Comment: Doesn't the function Book3 <- ts(Book3, [,3], start = 2016,1, frequency = 12) convert to a timeseries or is my logic wrong? @neilfws

Comment: That line of code generates an error `Error: unexpected '[' in "Book3 <- ts(Book3, ["`. So I am guessing that it did not convert `Book3` to ts.

Comment: I see, I'm getting that issue as well. Do you have any inclinations to why this error is being presented? 

The code is pointing towards book3 which is the dataframe. [,3] to only use the 3rd column of data "calls handled". And finally start = 2016,1 to start on 2016 January and frequency = 12 as its yearly data.

Comment: I think you want `Book3 <- ts(Book3[,3], frequency = 12, start = c(2016, 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax used to convert column 3 to a time series is incorrect. It should be:

```
Book3 <- ts(Book3[,3], frequency = 12, start = c(2016, 1))
```

and then:

```
autoplot(Book3)
```

[image]

Comment: Arguably should have been closed as a typo.